# Count non-NA observations by row in selected columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data frame:

```
Name  Color   L1    L2    R3 
Joe    Red    5.4   6.2   7.7
Eric   Blue   NA    4.1   6.1
Steve  Green  NA    NA    1.2
Mike   Red    NA    NA    NA
```

I would like to count the number of observations across columns L1, L2, and L3, but not count NA values. So I would like the above table to become:

```
Name  Color   L1    L2    R3    Count 
Joe    Red    5.4   6.2   7.7    3
Eric   Blue   NA    4.1   6.1    2
Steve  Green  NA    NA    1.2    1
Mike   Red    NA    NA    NA     0
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical matrix i.e. `is.na(df1[3:5])` returns a logical matrix where TRUE -> NA and FALSE -> nonNA, by negating (`!`), TRUE -> FALSE and viceversa.  Then, with `rowSums`, the TRUE (TRUE/FALSE -> 1/0) are added together

```
df1$Count <- rowSums(!is.na(df1[3:5]))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Count = rowSums(!is.na(select(., 3:5))))
```

-output

```
#    Name Color  L1  L2  R3 Count
#1   Joe   Red 5.4 6.2 7.7     3
#2  Eric  Blue  NA 4.1 6.1     2
#3 Steve Green  NA  NA 1.2     1
#4  Mike   Red  NA  NA  NA     0
```

---

Or if we need to use column names in a range, use the `select`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(Count = rowSums(!is.na(select(., L1:R3))))
```

NOTE: `rowSums` is vectorized and would be very fast

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Joe", "Eric", "Steve", "Mike"), Color = c("Red", 
"Blue", "Green", "Red"), L1 = c(5.4, NA, NA, NA), L2 = c(6.2, 
4.1, NA, NA), R3 = c(7.7, 6.1, 1.2, NA)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: would it be possible to use column names in the rowsums command rather than the location of the columns? I just figure it would be much easier in case the location of those columns changes

Comment: @rogues77 you can use a range of column names in `select`, updated the post

Comment: I might be making a mistake but i keep getting this error ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Count`.
x Input `Count` can't be recycled to size 826.
ℹ Input `Count` is `rowSums(!is.na(select(.,L1:R3)
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Count`.
x Input `Count` can't be recycled to size 826.
ℹ Input `Count` is `rowSums(!is.na(select(.,```

Comment: @rogues77 Not sure about your case.  I showed the example data as a reproducible one.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm surprised that your second solution using `rowSums()` + dplyr is so much faster than the answer below by Duck using `rowwise()` + `c_across()`!

Comment: @elarry `rowSums/rowMeans` are some of the fastest vectorized functions in `base R` that does row wise operation.  whereas `rowwise` is a slow loop

Comment: Good to know! I've been preferring tidyverse over base R for its readability, but `rowSums()` is such a clear win in this case! Many thanks, @akrun!

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Count=sum(!is.na(c_across(L1:R3))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Rowwise: 
  Name  Color    L1    L2    R3 Count
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 Joe   Red     5.4   6.2   7.7     3
2 Eric  Blue   NA     4.1   6.1     2
3 Steve Green  NA    NA     1.2     1
4 Mike  Red    NA    NA    NA       0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Joe", "Eric", "Steve", "Mike"), Color = c("Red", 
"Blue", "Green", "Red"), L1 = c(5.4, NA, NA, NA), L2 = c(6.2, 
4.1, NA, NA), R3 = c(7.7, 6.1, 1.2, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple base R solution:

```
df1$Count <- apply(df1[3:5], 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
```