# pairwise subtraction of columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, apply

I was wondering is there a way to automate (e.g., loop) the subtraction of (`X2-X1`), (`X3-X1`), (`X3-X2`) in my `data` below and add them as three new columns to the `data`?

```
m="
id X1 X2 X3
A  1  0  4
B  2  2  2
C  3  4  1"

data <- read.table(text = m, h = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74303789/6461462); we basically just need to change the function that we are using in `map2_dfc`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

combn(names(data)[-1], 2) %>% 
  map2_dfc(.x = .[1,], .y = .[2,], 
           .f = ~transmute(data, !!paste0(.y, "-", .x) := !!sym(.y) - !!sym(.x))) %>% 
  bind_cols(data, .)

#>   id X1 X2 X3 X2-X1 X3-X1 X3-X2
#> 1  A  1  0  4    -1     3     4
#> 2  B  2  2  2     0     0     0
#> 3  C  3  4  1     1    -2    -3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `combn`:

```r
dif <- combn(data[-1], 2, \(x) x[, 2] - x[, 1])
colnames(dif) <- combn(names(data)[-1], 2, \(x) paste(x[2], x[1], sep = "-"))

cbind(data, dif)
#  id X1 X2 X3 X2-X1 X3-X1 X3-X2
#1  A  1  0  4    -1     3     4
#2  B  2  2  2     0     0     0
#3  C  3  4  1     1    -2    -3
```

Comment: Thanks! it just seems a bit too complicated, is there a way to possibly simplify the code?

Comment: Well, if you already know the columns index, you can replace them in `cols`. Otherwise, if a list is okay, you can skip the `do.call`

Comment: It's much simpler now

Comment: This is very nice! +1